# Talking to a server in Win32; how do I see the server's response?

Tags: winapi, smtp, winsock, visual-c++

I am new to Win32 programming.

```
sprintf(lpszBuff,"HELO Mail-Server\r\n");
     send(s,lpszBuff,strlen(lpszBuff),0);     
     recv(s,lpszBuff,100,0);
  cout << lpszBuff;
```

In here I connect to a local mail server. The buffer contains the request I send, the same buffer contains the reply send by the browser. How do I see the reply? `cout <<buffer` doesn't show any output. I am doing this on VC++ 2008.

Comment: @Michael Hey... thnx for the editing..

Comment: just a little head's up: when there is an obvious issue with your question formatting etc., make sure you do a refresh of the page before editing in case someone else has already done it for you. You saved an edit over top of one i had just done and @Michael had to fix that along with rephrasing your title & text.

Comment: What does debug and variable watch say? Do you get the recv() function to fill the buffer? Could you perhaps paste more code? Initialization, winsock settings, etc. to pastebin or the like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a blocking or non-blocking socket?  What is the return value of `recv()`?  Chances are, you are reading before there is anything available to read, and `recv()` is returning an error code that you are ignoring.  What you have shown is way too simplistic.  Proper socket coding requires more logic (looping when incomplete sends/reads occur, using `select()` to detect socket states, error handling, etc)

Answer (score 0):

When you talk to SMTP server as a sender, the reception/mail-server should send 220 command to sender first.

```
     R: 220 BBN-UNIX.ARPA Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready
     S: HELO USC-ISIF.ARPA
     R: 250 BBN-UNIX.ARPA

     S: MAIL FROM:<Smith@USC-ISIF.ARPA>
     R: 250 OK

     S: RCPT TO:<Jones@BBN-UNIX.ARPA>
     R: 250 OK

     S: RCPT TO:<Green@BBN-UNIX.ARPA>
     R: 550 No such user here

     S: RCPT TO:<Brown@BBN-UNIX.ARPA>
     R: 250 OK

     S: DATA
     R: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
     S: Blah blah blah...
     S: ...etc. etc. etc.
     S: .
     R: 250 OK

     S: QUIT
     R: 221 BBN-UNIX.ARPA Service closing transmission channel
```

R: Receptor -- local SMTP server 
S: indicates the local Sender

Basically you should:

```
recv(s,lpszBuff,200,0); // for 220
cout << lpszBuff;
sprintf(lpszBuff,"HELO Mail-Server\r\n");
send(s,lpszBuff,strlen(lpszBuff),0);     
recv(s,lpszBuff,100,0);
cout << lpszBuff;
```

Make sure your socket is in block mode.